# Deserialize json data getting as string in spark java

Tags: java, json, string, apache-spark, dataset

We have upstream system from where we receive events on kafka topic.
Upstream send the events in Json format but as a string and also they dont have fixed attributes in the json.

Below is example of event.
Value for "key" is another JSON but as a String and same applies for "key2_4". We have lot more fields in the json string and its not sure that they will have all fields too.

```
{
    "key" : "{
                "key1" : "value1",
                "key2" : "{
                            "key2_1" : "value2_1",
                            "key2_2" : "value2_2",
                            "key2_3" : "value2_3",
                            "key2_4" : "{
                                        "key2_4_1" : "value4_1",
                                        "key2_4_2" : "value4_2"
                                        }"
                          }",
                "key3" : "value3"
            }"
}
```

We are using spark to process these events and read some of attributes from the JSON string and persist as a separate file for further use.

What are the ways to de-serialize/process this kind of json and also is there any Spark Java api which can help read the attributes considering the performance as we have lots of events to process.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: do we know what fields to fetch and persist? also, does these events have fixed format? perhaps https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#get_json_object, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json might be useful, have a look

Comment: yes we know the fields to be fetched.
fixed format as in we know that we will get json as a string with many attributes optional.

Thanks for sharing link, will have a look on that

Comment: then use `get_json_object(json_txt, path) - Extracts a json object from path.`

Comment: both the fucntion will not work as json is in string. if i print the schema, below is what i get.

`root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)`

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried defining a schema in spark for the json and then create dataset from the kafka message?

Comment: @RajaAyaz  As i told, we can not have fixed schema and and events which we are getting is Json as a String.

Comment: @SomeshwarKale  yes i have tried. Logically its string so not sure if any of the json function will apply.

Comment: if you are dealing with json strings, as a suggestion, why not use a json parser e.g. JSONObject from org.json? would that solve your problem?

Comment: @RajaAyaz looking for some solution specific to spark(java, if any), else yes i have some json api in mind to use.

Comment: I think go for json api like org.json, its lightening fast, and very lightweight operation. It would be a good choice. And inside a spark job, it executes on Spark. I don't need know if spark provides native support. In a dataframe, you can use spark to get fields from Json. Using any api is perfectly fine.

Comment: take a look at this if it helps, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62230151/4758823

Comment: @SomeshwarKale : thanks but thats not my use case. let me know if you have any doubts on question.